# absolute value of the addition of two complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on a problem, and along the way have to take $|a-z|^2$, where $a$ and $z$ are complex.  I know the triangle inequality, but I am trying to find a formula for $|z_1-z_2|$ = ?

Comment: I think : $|z_1-z_2|:=\sqrt{(z_1-z_2)\overline{(z_1-z_2)}}$. Another way to see that, if $z=x+iy$ then $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: If I square that, how would I break it down?  I know from a comment later on in the problem that $|a-z|^2$ = $|a|^2 -2Re(\overline{a}z) + |z|^2$, so that is the form that I am trying to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my comment :

$$|a-z|^2=\sqrt{(a-z)\overline{(a-z)}}^2=(a-z)\overline{(a-z)} $$

$$|a-z|^2=(a-z)(\bar{a}-\bar{z})=a\bar{a}-z\bar{a}-z\bar{a}+z\bar{z}=|a|^2-(a\bar{z}+\overline{a\bar{z}})+|z|^2$$

$$|a-z|^2=|a|^2-2\Re(a\bar{z})+|z|^2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
|z_1-z_2|^2 = (z_1-z_2)\left(\overline{z_1-z_2}\right) = |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2-(z_1\overline{z_2} + \overline{z_1}z_2)
$$
Then 
$$
|z_1-z_2|= \sqrt{|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2-(z_1\overline{z_2} + \overline{z_1}z_2)}
$$